# Matlab: How to convert a string to a number

Tags: string, matlab, numbers

How can i convert a string to a number? 
 **number_of_plots** = **'4'** but i want **4** without ''

```
Tabel_Cell = table2cell(diagramoptions) ;
idx= strfind(Tabel_Cell(:,1), 'number_of_plots');
idx = find(not(cellfun('isempty',idx)));
number_of_plots = Tabel_Cell{idx,2}
%number_of_plots1=double(number_of_plots);
%number_of_plots1=str2num(number_of_plots);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str2num` to convert strings to numbers.

If you want to convert them into floats rather use `str2double` which is faster (and safer) than `str2num`